# C# Triangle Program Question

Tags: c#

I am working on a problem for my CIS college class. We are to draw four triangle asterisks using only for loops and Console.Write(" "); and Console.WriteLine();

Here is a link to a picture

[Triangles](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/triangles.png/)

There is one extra space than I need.

```
    class Diamond
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int row; // the current row
            int stars; // the number of stars
            int spaces; // the number of spaces

            // top half (1st five lines)
            for ( row = 1; row <= 11; row++ )
            {
            for ( spaces = 1; spaces > row; spaces-- )
            Console.Write( " " );

                for ( stars = 1; stars <= row - 1; stars++ )
                    Console.Write( "*" );

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    } // end outer for


            //Triangle B

            for (row = 0; row <= 11; row++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (spaces = 10; spaces > row; spaces--)
                    Console.Write("*");

                for (stars = 1; stars <= row - 1; stars++)
                    Console.Write("");
            } // end outer for

            //Triangle C

            for (row = 0; row <= 11; row++)
            {
                for (stars = 0; stars <= row - 1; stars++)
                    Console.Write(" ");

                for (spaces = 10; spaces > row; spaces--)
                    Console.Write("*");

                Console.WriteLine();
            } // end outer for


            //Triangle D

            for (row = 1; row <= 10; row++)
            {
                for (spaces = 10; spaces > row; spaces--)
                    Console.Write(" ");

                for (stars = 0; stars <= row - 1; stars++)
                    Console.Write("*");

                Console.WriteLine();
            } // end outer for


            Console.ReadLine();
        } // end Main
     } // end class Diamond
```

Any hints or solution to my problem?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the indices?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something simple!

I just changed spaces = 10 in triangle c to 11 and made row = 1 like all the rest.

Thank you for your helpful hint =)